# Javascript - Used a loop to see old facebook messages in Chrome, don't know how to make it stop

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome

I used the following javascript in the develop tab to see old Facebook messages. There are thousands of messages and it just keeps going. Loading one month of messages took 30 minutes. I only need messages for the last year, but it looks like it will keep loading until it hits our first messages in 2010! I don't know how to make it stop without losing everything that it has already loaded. Do you know how I can stop the loop from executing?

```
setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById('see_older')
   .getElementsByClassName('content')[0].click();
}, 500);
```

Comment: First, you are probably loading the same set of messages several time, because you are not waiting for a request return to do the next. You need some callback to wait for the response, check the dates and request the next page only if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to stop right now, and don't want to refresh the page, a 'dirty' simple solution would be to open you browsers' console and execute the following code:

```
 for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++)
    window.clearInterval(i);
```

Most major browsers will assign a small number as the ID so just looping over all possible numbers should work. But as mentioned, it would be better to store a reference to your interval in a variable so you could clear it using the clearInterval() method.

Answer (score 1):

you should declare a variable for that interval function and then you can use clearinterval(theVarYouDeclared) to stop it